# How can get the yearly values from weekly data for a specific year in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from pandas_datareader import data, wb

#here I take the stocks from quandl
start = dt.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime.today()
stocks = ["WIKI/AAPL", "WIKI/TSLA", "WIKI/IBM", "WIKI/LNKD"]
key = "fmP5pv-nVvhKmjWwF7Fb"
df = data.DataReader(stocks, "quandl", start, end, api_key=key)

# Here I create a dataFrame with the Volume values.
vol = df['Volume']

# Here I aggregate the data of Volume to weekly
vol['week'] = vol.index.week
vol['year'] = vol.index.year
week = vol.groupby(['year','week']).sum()
```

Now I'd like to find all the volume traded in the year of 2015, maybe deleting week column band using groupby. Something like that

```
year = vol.groupby(['2015']).sum()
year.head()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here. Maybe if you detail out what you're looking for, or what the end result should look like, I'd be closer on my answer.

you can group by like this:

```
vol.drop('week',axis=1).groupby('year').sum()

Symbols      WIKIAAPL       WIKIIBM      WIKILNKD      WIKITSLA
year                                                           
2015     1.306432e+10  1.306432e+10  1.306432e+10  1.306432e+10
2016     9.685872e+09  9.685872e+09  9.685872e+09  9.685872e+09
2017     6.640747e+09  6.640747e+09  6.640747e+09  6.640747e+09
2018     2.148944e+09  2.148944e+09  2.148944e+09  2.148944e+09
```

Or just getting totals for `2015`

```
vol[vol.year == 2015].sum()

Symbols
WIKIAAPL    1.306432e+10
WIKIIBM     1.306432e+10
WIKILNKD    1.306432e+10
WIKITSLA    1.306432e+10
week        6.886000e+03
year        5.077800e+05
dtype: float64
```

Looks like the volume values are the same in your `df` for all 4 stocks. I'd double check that.